# Display React component only when attribute is not null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**MyReactComponent** returns a hyperlink and a message after looking up an API using the **name** value. However I would like to render this component (which includes making the API call) only when name is not empty. Would the below solve the purpose or should I approach this differently?

```
   <dt hidden={null == name || '' === name.trim()}>
      <MyReactComponent name={name || ' '} />
    </dt>
```

Comment: {name && name.trim() !== "" && <MyReactComponent />}, so in the case MyReactComponent will be rendered if name has some value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way you can do this :

```
{(name && name.trim() !== '') &&
    <MyReactComponent name={name} />
}
```

You can learn more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `hidden` attribute, you can render your component with ternary operator:

```
{name ? <MyReactComponent name={name} /> : null}
```